# Is it possible to add an interceptor to all answers when using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

Suppose I have a validation annotation on my Interface method to validate input arguments and return value.
Is it possible at the moment (V 1.9.5) to tell Mockito to invoke this validator during the invocation process?

The background would be to prevent developers from writing unrealistic tests by mocking the given interface in a way that violates the specified validator.

So what I would want is to register something like

```
class MyAnswerInterceptor<T> implements AnswerInterceptor<T> {
    @Override
    public Answer<T> intercept(final Answer<T> answer) {
        return new Answer<T>() {
            @Override
            public T answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                validateArguments(invocation);
                T result = answer.answer(invocation);
                validateReturnValue(result);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to be called on every answer of a given mock.
Is this possible at all? I've looked into the code, also to check if I could hack in at some point (even using reflection or the like), but it seems due to entanglement of instance creation and logic, it's hardly possible to achieve what I want (i.e. stuff like `MockHandler mockHandler = new MockHandlerFactory().create(settings);` makes it impossible to hook in and put custom stuff on top without patching and deploying the whole thing...)

Any insight would be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Found one solution that works, namely write my own `when(T methodCall)` method, inside of which I delegate to `Mockito.when` and then wrap the OngoingStubbing into a Javassist proxy and catch all `thenBlubb(..)` methods wrapping the respective answer into my interceptor and returning the OngoingStubbing proxy. Anyway, this is certainly not the neatest way, so if anyone knows a more beautiful way, I'm still open to suggestions ;-) (in particular it sucks to handle all `thenBlubb(..)` methods and it will demand further attention on each upgrade...)

Comment: Also, your solution won't work for methods such as void methods, where you need the doXxx/when syntax in place of the when/thenXxx syntax.  Unless you make your own versions of each of the doXxx methods.

Comment: Hi! You want to mix into simple unit tests some very complicated logic. Why not just unit test the validator itself separately from the logic of where it is used and test it altogether in an integration test?

Comment: Mhmm, I don't know if the logic is that complicated, it's four lines in an Answer... The idea was to apply something like design by contract, specify a "contract" via annotation in production code, and then ensure with the above technique, that developers will actually mock the components in a way that obeys the contract as well. If it's a good idea, I don't know, but I've come across unit tests with wrong assumptions (mocked in a way that can't happen in actual production code) more than once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that by creating a custom [`MockMaker`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/plugins/MockMaker.html).

> MockMaker is an extension point that makes it possible to use custom dynamic proxies and avoid using the default cglib/asm/objenesis implementation

Our custom implementation delegates all the complex stuff to the default `MockMaker`: `CglibMockMaker`. It "decorates" only the [`createMock`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/plugins/MockMaker.html#createMock(org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings,%20org.mockito.invocation.MockHandler)) method by registering on the `settings` parameter an [`InvocationListener`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/listeners/InvocationListener.html). This listener will be notified when an `invocation` have been done allowing use to call `validateArguments` and `validateReturnValue`.

```
import org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker;
import org.mockito.invocation.Invocation;
import org.mockito.invocation.MockHandler;
import org.mockito.listeners.InvocationListener;
import org.mockito.listeners.MethodInvocationReport;
import org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings;
import org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker;

public class ValidationMockMaker implements MockMaker {
    private final MockMaker delegate = new CglibMockMaker();

    public ValidationMockMaker() {
    }
    @Override
    public <T> T createMock(MockCreationSettings<T> settings, MockHandler handler) {
        settings.getInvocationListeners().add(new InvocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void reportInvocation(MethodInvocationReport methodInvocationReport) {
                Invocation invocation = (Invocation) methodInvocationReport.getInvocation();
                validateArguments(invocation.getArguments());
                validateReturnValue(methodInvocationReport.getReturnedValue());
            }
        });
        return delegate.createMock(settings, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public MockHandler getHandler(Object mock) {
        return delegate.getHandler(mock);
    }

    @Override
    public void resetMock(Object mock, MockHandler newHandler, MockCreationSettings settings) {
        delegate.resetMock(mock, newHandler, settings);
    }

    protected void validateArguments(Object... arguments) {
//        Arrays.stream(arguments).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
    }

    private void validateReturnValue(Object result) {
//        Objects.requireNonNull(result);
    }
}
```

---

Last but not least, we need to tell to Mockito to use our implementation. This is possible by adding a file

```
mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
```

containing our MockMaker class name:

```
ValidationMockMaker
```

See [`Using the extension point`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/plugins/MockMaker.html) section in the javadoc.

Comment: Awesome, that looks exactly like the thing I need, thanks a lot!!! I'll try that approach as soon as possible :-)